# Cauchy-Schwarz on real vector space: $| \langle u, v \rangle | = \| u \| \cdot \| v \| \iff u =\frac {\langle u, v \rangle} {\langle v, v \rangle} v$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Cauchy-Schwarz on real vector space: $| \langle u, v \rangle | = \| u \| \cdot \| v \| \iff u =\frac {\langle u, v \rangle} {\langle v, v \rangle} v$

Proving that $u =\frac {\langle u, v \rangle} {\langle v, v \rangle} v$ imply equality is easy by substitution of $u$.

However, I cannot prove that equality holds imply $u =\frac {\langle u, v \rangle} {\langle v, v \rangle} v$.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: See [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). You'll find the answer

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23522/proofs-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality particularly the last answer for a very elegant solution.

Comment: While not quite a duplicate, this question is already contained in several others (simply search "Cauchy Schwarz". I'm voting to close.

Comment: Consider using \| u \| instead of ||u|| to get $\| u \|$ instead of $||u||$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$
\lvert\langle u,v\rangle\rvert=\|u\|\|v\|,
$$
iff
$u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent.

Proof. In both are equal to 0, then they are linearly dependent.
Assume that $v\ne 0$ and set
$$
f(\lambda)=\|\lambda v+u\|^2.
$$
Clearly $f(\lambda)\ge 0$, for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. But
$$
\|\lambda v+u\|^2=\langle \lambda v+u,\lambda v+u\rangle=\|v\|^2\lambda^2+2\langle v,u\rangle
\lambda+\|u\|^2,
$$
which means that the roots of the quadratic polynomial above are either equal or complex or equivalently its discriminant is non-positive:
$$
0\ge \Delta=4\langle v,u\rangle^2-4\|u\|^2\|v\|^2.
$$
Equality above implies that 
$$
\|\lambda v+u\|^2,
$$
for some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, which means that $u=-\lambda v$. Hence...

Comment: So, what is the value of that some $\lambda$?