# Is it true that $\Big(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\Big)^p\leq\sum(a_n)^p$?

Tags: inequality, summation

More precisely, is the inequality $\Big(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\Big)^p\leq\sum(a_n)^p$ true for $a_n\geq0$ for all $n\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$ and $p\in(0,\infty)$?

EDIT: And if so, will it also hold for an infinite sum under the same conditions?

Comment: For $p>1$, see the answers to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803056) question.

Comment: @Lucian: That question only addresses integers $p>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Neither direction on the inequality holds in general.

Consider $a_1 = a_2 = \ldots = a_n = 1$ and $p>1$, then

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^p = n^p.$$

However,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n {a_i}^p = n < n^p$$

since $p>1$; thus,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n {a_i}^p < \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^p.$$

If instead $0<p<1$, then $n^p < n$, giving

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^p < \sum_{i=1}^n {a_i}^p.$$

Comment: Ok, so this doesn't hold in general if $p>1$, and you gave one example for when it does work when $0<p<1$ - does it always hold in this case, then?

Comment: It does hold for (only for) $0<p\le1$.

Comment: @QuangHoang You're right.