# Need Help interpreting a proof to Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I found this proof for Cauchy-Schwarz on this forum. Can someone help explain how does the absolute value of |cos($\theta$) < 1| help prove the inequality?

[Proofs of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23522/proofs-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality)

[image: Proof]

Comment: Read it backwards, starting with the (presumably) well known $\;\;-1 \le \cos \theta \le 1$ $\;\;\iff\;\; \mid \cos \theta \mid \leq 1$ $\;\;\implies\;\; \mid \|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|\cos \theta \mid \leq \|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|$ $\;\;\iff\;\; \mid\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}\mid \leq \|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|\,$.

Comment: The second line is wrong. $|x \cdot y| = \|x\| \|y\| |\cos \theta|$, not $\|x\| \|y\| \cos \theta$. More importantly, this argument seems potentially circular, depending on how $\theta$ is defined.